# Noise in Eigenvalues plot

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am trying to Plot Eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian, but I am getting noisy plot, which is incorrect.  Here is the code.

```
A1 = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 0}};
   A2 = {{0, -I, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, I, 0}};
   A3 = {{0, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}};
   A4 = {{0, -I, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, I}, {0, 0, -I, 0}};
   A5 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
   A6 = {{0, 0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, I, 0}, {0, -I, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0, 0}};
   A7 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
   A8 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
H[d_, λ_, β_, m_] := 
  a (Sin[x] A1 + Sin[ky] A2) + A3 β + 
   d A4 + (t Cos[z] + 2 b (2 - Cos[x] - Cos[ky])) A5 + α*
    Sin[ky] A6 + λ Sin[z] A7+m*A8;
   ky = 0;
   a = 1;
   b = 1;
   t = 1.5;
   α = 0.3;
   Plot3D[Eigenvalues[H[0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0]][[4]], {x, -π, π}, {z, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

By default, the eigenvalues are ordered by absolute value. All the eigenvalues of this particular matrix have the *same* absolute value plus some rounding errors. Thus, it can easily happen, that the fourth eigenvalue is positive or negative, depending on the parameters.

You can use `Max` to plot the largest eigenvalue:

```
Plot3D[Max@Eigenvalues[H[0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may use the `"Criteria"` suboption of the Method `"Arnoldi"`:

```
Plot3D[
  Eigenvalues[
   H[0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0], -1, 
   Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}
   ], 
  {x, - Pi, Pi}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Thanks @ Henrik Schumacher

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you pick the 4th element, but maybe this will help:

```
ev4 = Eigenvalues[H[p, q, r, s]][[4]] /. 
   Thread[{p, q, r, s} -> {0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0}];
Plot3D[ev4, {x, -π, π}, {z, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Michael E2, Is it possible to do this with an equation by the contourplot. Like 
    ev4 = Eigenvalues[H[p, q, r, s]][[4]] /. 
       Thread[{p, q, r, s} -> {0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0}];
     ContourPlot[ev4==-0.5, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]. In my case this is not working.

Comment: @HazoorImran Yes, but set the value `-0.5` on the right hand side to something bigger.  For example `ContourPlot[ev4 == 2, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`.

Comment: Thanks @ Michael E2, Yes this work.