# Mathematica's Plot3D function gives me a scrambled plot

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, physics, lattices

When I plot the band structure of the Lieb lattice, which has the Hamiltonian given in this code, I get a scrambled plot in the output. I've tried the exact same procedure with many different lattices (square, graphene) and I get the right output but somehow Mathematica is not liking this Hamiltonian in particular.

```
        t = 0.1; (*hopping potential*)
        h = {{0, -t (1 + E^(-I*ky)), 0}, {0, 0, -t (1 + E^(I*kx))}, {0, 0, 
            0}}; (*Defining part of the Hamiltonian*)
        h = h + h\[ConjugateTranspose]; (*Making Hamiltonian Hermitian*)
        h // MatrixForm (*Viewing Hamiltonian as a matrix*)
        Plot3D[Eigenvalues[
        h], {kx, -π, π}, {ky, -π, π}] (*Plotting \Eigenvalues of Hamiltonian with wavenumber to obtain bandstructure*)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: You need to `Evaluate` or `Sort` the eigenvalues in the argument of `Plot3D` - for some reason, `Plot3D` always "jumps" between the three different bands otherwise. So either `Plot3D[Evaluate@Eigenvalues[h],...]` or `Plot3D[Sort@Eigenvalues[h],...]` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195721/noise-in-eigenvalues-plot, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126981/discontinuities-in-eigenvalues-plotting-with-plot3d, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39747/how-to-plot-several-functions-without-jumping-multiple-eigenvalues-of-a-system

Comment: @LukasLang, Thank you very much! Both Sort and Evaluate fix my problem. There still seems to be a couple of breaks in the surface and the Evaluate function shows that the top and bottom bands are swapped at these breaks. This seems to be an artifact to me because I believe the bands should be smooth and continuous. Otherwise it looks much better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = 0.1;
h = {{0, -t (1 + E^(-I ky)), 0}, {0, 0, -t (1 + E^(I kx))}, {0, 0, 0}};
ham = h + Assuming[{Element[kx, Reals], Element[ky, Reals]}, 
      Refine[ConjugateTranspose[h]]]);
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -0.1 \left(1+e^{-i \text{ky}}\right) & 0 \\
 -0.1 \left(1+e^{i \text{ky}}\right) & 0 & -0.1 \left(1+e^{i \text{kx}}\right) \\
 0 & -0.1 \left(1+e^{-i \text{kx}}\right) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

You may find the eigenvalues using:

```
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[ham]]
```

$$\left\{0,-0.141421 \sqrt{\cos (\text{kx})+\cos (\text{ky})+2},-0.141421
   \sqrt{\cos (\text{kx})+\cos (\text{ky})+2}\right\}$$

You may use `Plot3D` now.

Comment: Thank you very much. This also solves my problem and shines light on the mathematical form of the eigenvalues!